# Need assistance explaining the purpose and operation of a specific method

Tags: java, methods

Just going over some programming questions before my exam, and i'm confused on this question...

With respect to the `Java` classes detailed in Appendix A explain the purpose and operation of the method `matchProgrammeCode()`. (10)

Functional interface – 2 marks, local class – 3 marks, operation – 5 marks

Appendix A
Student

```
 public class Student {
    int studentId;
    String studentName;
    String programmeCode;
    Collection<ModuleRegistration> registeredModules;

    static int noStudents = 0;

    public Student() { … }

    public Student(String studentName, String programmeCode) { … }

    public Student(int studentId, String studentName,
                   String programmeCode) { … }

    public int getStudentId(){ … }

    public String getStudentName(){ … }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) { … }

    public String getProgrammeCode(){ … }

    public void setProgrammeCode(String programmeCode) { … }

    public void addModule(ModuleRegistration moduleRegistration)
    { … }

    @Override
    public String toString() { … }

    interface CheckStudent { boolean test(Student s); }

    class CheckStudentProgrammeCode implements CheckStudent {
        String programmeCode;

        CheckStudentProgrammeCode(String programmeCode) {
            this.programmeCode = programmeCode;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean test(Employee s) {
            return s.getProgrammeCode().equals(this.programmeCode);
        }
    }

    public boolean matchProgrammeCode(String programmeCode) {
        CheckStudentProgrammeCode tester =
            new CheckStudentProgrammeCode(String programmeCode);
        return tester.test(this);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I think you are unclear on this keyword which is passed as an argument inside matchProgrammeCode method. You can refer this http://www.javatpoint.com/this-keyword

Answer (score 1):

This method actually does nothing more than comparing the `programmeCode` attribute of your instance of `Student`to a String you give it as a parameter. 
You could then use it like this in your main:

```
Student s = Student();
s.setProgrammeCode("Hello World");
if(s.matchProgrammeCode("Hello World")) {
    /* Programmecode is equal :) */
}
```

It's super hard to explain what goes on in your code because I don't know how advanced you are at Java programming, but I've edited your code so that only the relevant part to the question will stay and added some comments that hopefully explain it well enough:

```
public class Student {
    String programmeCode;

    public Student() { … }

    // Everything that implements this interface will assure it has the method "test"
    interface CheckStudent { boolean test(Student s); }

    // Implements CheckStudent, therefore has to have the method "test"
    // Also is an inner class of your Student-class
    class CheckStudentProgrammeCode implements CheckStudent {
        String programmeCode;

        CheckStudentProgrammeCode(String programmeCode) {
            // Constructor safes a string
            this.programmeCode = programmeCode;
        }
        // Concrete implementation of the test-method which is required after implementing the interface
        @Override
        public boolean test(Employee s) {
            // equals compares the programmeCode that was safed by the constructor with the s.getProgrammeCode() of the given object
            // then returns the outcome of the equal method - true if they are equal, false if not
            // It is equivalent to:
            // if(s.getProgrammeCode().equals(this.programmeCode)) {return true;} else {return false;}
            return s.getProgrammeCode().equals(this.programmeCode);
        }
    }

    public boolean matchProgrammeCode(String programmeCode) {
        // Creating a new, local instance of CheckStudentProgrammeCode and passing the
        // String programmeCode directly from the parameter of the method into the instance's constructor
        CheckStudentProgrammeCode tester =
            new CheckStudentProgrammeCode(String programmeCode);
        // The test-method takes the instance of Student itself (this) and returns a boolean, which will then be passed directly into the return of the method
        return tester.test(this);
    }
}
```